# How do I get the string representation out of a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Really dumb question but, for instance, given:

```
var $foo = $('<div>bar</div>');
```

How would I get the `'<div>bar</div>'` back out?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys... this is probably the worst question I've asked on here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to append it to a container, then call `.html()` on that.

This is because `.html()` only gives you the content.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/ttYXG/

```
var $foo = $('<div>bar</div>');

$('<div />').append($foo).html();
```

Comment: @longda - If needed, you can get rid of the wrapper `<div>` with `$foo.unwrap();`. May not really be necessary since `$foo` still references your original element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<h1>Test</h1>")[0].outerHTML
```

Returns: `<h1>Test</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
var txt = $foo.text();
```

If you want *everything* in your element:

```
var html = $foo.html();
```

*edit* — oh wait; you want the outer tag too.  Hmm. Well you could clone it, wrap it in *another* div, and get the text or html from that, but something tells me there may be a better way:

```
var $otherFoo = $foo.clone().wrap('<div/');
var html = $otherFoo.parent().html(); // fixed thanks to @patrick dw
```

(or do it like @patrick suggests; whatever.)

Comment: `$otherFoo` is referencing the cloned `$foo`. You would need to traverse up to its parent (the wrapper `<div>`) in order to get its `.html()`.

Comment: oh right; sorry @patrick I make that mistake all the time in actual code!!  Fixing post now.